# C# Scale with the pixel of the mouse position, but there will be an offset between the two

Tags: c#, image, winforms, gdi+

Zoom in on a certain pixel of the image, and there is an offset between the pixel position and the mouse after zooming. But I am zooming at the position of the mouse. At this time, the mouse is on this pixel. There should be no offset, and it should be completely coincident.

I draw a rectangle in this pixel， like this:
[image]
but after I zooming the image, this pixel is not at the position:
[image]

```
  protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
      float tempRatio = 1 / Ratio;

      float delta = 0.1f;
      delta = tempRatio / 5;
      float newRatio = tempRatio + (e.Delta / 120 * delta);
      newRatio = 1 / newRatio;
      if (newRatio < 0.0005 || newRatio > 10) return;
      CalWindowsTranslationAfterZoom(e.Location, newRatio);
      Ratio = newRatio;
      Draw(e.Location);
     }

    private void CalWindowsTranslationAfterZoom(Point mouse, float ratio)
    {
        //get position in canvas
        PointF oldCoord = CoordInCavas(mouse, Ratio);
        //AfterZoom
        PointF newLeftUp = new PointF(-(Width * ratio - _image.Width) / 2,
             -(Height * ratio - _image.Height) / 2);
        PointF deltaLeftUp = new PointF(newLeftUp.X - _leftUp.X, newLeftUp.Y - 
        _leftUp.Y);
        PointF newOriOffset = new PointF(OriginsOffset.X + deltaLeftUp.X, 
         OriginsOffset.Y + deltaLeftUp.Y);
        PointF newCoord = CoordInCavas(mouse, newOriOffset, ratio);

        PointF deviation = new PointF();
        deviation.X = (newCoord.X - oldCoord.X);
        deviation.Y = (newCoord.Y - oldCoord.Y);

        PointF offset = new PointF();
        offset.X = newOriOffset.X - deviation.X;
        offset.Y = newOriOffset.Y - deviation.Y;

        OriginsOffset = offset;
        Ratio = ratio;
   }   
//Drawing 
private void Draw(Point mouse)
{
    Graphics g = DoubleBuffered.Graphics;
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
    g.Clear(DoubleBuffered.BackColor);

    if (_image != null)
    {
        g.DrawImage(_image, -OriginsOffset.X / Ratio, -OriginsOffset.Y / Ratio,
           _image.Width / Ratio, _image.Height / Ratio);
        _vGraphics = new VGraphics(this);
        _vGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Green, Rectangle);

    }
}
 private PointF CoordInCavas(PointF coordInWindow, float ratio)
    {
        PointF coordAfterScale = new PointF(coordInWindow.X * ratio, coordInWindow.Y * 
         ratio);
        PointF coord = new PointF();
        coord.X = coordAfterScale.X + OriginsOffset.X;
        coord.Y = coordAfterScale.Y + OriginsOffset.Y;
        return coord;

    }
```

Comment: Just a guess, but your dividing in some of the methods. It might be a rounding issue. Try casting every number in your calculation to float.
e.g.:    -((float)Width * ratio - (float)_image.Width) / 2f

Comment: i find some problem that for example  after scaleing i want draw image width 830 pixel, but it just show 827pixel in screen